How to stop nvcc from reordering clock instructions?
In the following snippet nvcc (CUDA 12.5) 'helpfully' reorders the clock statement. This causes the timings to be off by a factor 26x.
#include <cuda.h>
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ int dedupe(int a) {
  constexpr auto all = -1u;
  const auto start = clock64();
  const auto dupemask = __match_any_sync(all, a);
  const auto leader = __clz(dupemask);
  const auto end = clock64();
  const auto time = int(end - start);
  printf("tid: %i, dupemask: $%x, leader: %i, time: %i\n", threadIdx.x, dupemask, leader, time);
  return leader;
}

__global__ void dostuff() {
    const auto tid = threadIdx.x;
    const auto leader = dedupe(tid);
}

int main() {
  dostuff<<<1, 32>>>();
  return cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}

The dedupe function compiles to:
 CS2R R2, SR_CLOCKLO         // start = clock
 S2R R8, SR_TID.X            // tid = threadIdx.x
 MATCH.ANY R9, R8            // __match_any_sync
 CS2R R4, SR_CLOCKLO         // end = clock <<-- reordered
 FLO.U32 R10, R9             // __clz
 ... 

Giving me a time of 15 cycles, however the real latency of this snippet is closer to 400 cycles.
How do I force nvcc to never reorder the call to clock?
Note that replacing the clock64() with a volatile asm statement does not work:
__device__ uint64_t myclock() {
  uint64_t result;
  asm volatile ("mov.u64 %0, %%clock64;" : "=l"(result) :: "memory");
  return result;
}


The trick is to mark the clock assignments and all assignments in between as volatile.
  ...
  const auto volatile start = clock64();
  const auto volatile dupemask = __match_any_sync(all, a);
  const auto volatile leader = __clz(dupemask);        //yes I know the bug
  //const auto volatile leader = 31 - __clz(dupemask); //correct, but largely masks the OPs timing issue.
  const auto volatile end = clock64();
  ...

This yields the following assembly and gives the correct time for this snippet: 396 clock cycles.
 CS2R R2, SR_CLOCKLO          //start = clock
 S2R R8, SR_TID.X             //threadIdx.x
 MATCH.ANY R9, R8             //match_any_sync
 FLO.U32 R10, R9              //clz
 IADD3 R10, -R10, 0x1f, RZ    //extra code due to me not writing leader = 31 - __clz  
 CS2R R4, SR_CLOCKLO          //end = clock 

Note that just marking the clock64() assignments as volatile is not enough, that works sometimes, but not always.
Here's the link on Godbolt: https://cuda.godbolt.org/z/zEEvsh7xW

You're probably fine with editing the question before anyone writes another answer.

Shouldn't it be enough to mark the end of each "dependency chain" as volatile? In this example that's just one volatile less, but for longer regions in code it should make "instrumentation" much easier, especially if there is just one dependency chain end.

Hm, that's an interesting thought, perhaps yes.
